# Third law of thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

Does Third Law of thermodynamics violates Quantum Mechanics, I mean Why third law of Thermodynamics holds if we think about it in terms of Quantum Mechanics ?

Comment: Can you be more specific?why should 3rd law of thermodynamics violate quantum mechanics?

Comment: I am not saying that it violates quantum mechanics, but I am just wondering why third law of thermodynamics holds in terms of Quantum Mechanics like (degeneracy....)

Comment: Note the caveat [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_law_of_thermodynamics), "and this statement of the third law holds true if the perfect crystal has only *one* minimum energy state."

Comment: Somebody told me, that for a system with a large number of degree of freedom, the third law of entropy should be $Lim_{T\rightarrow 0, N\rightarrow \infty} S/N=0$. I am not sure about the order of the limits though.

Answer (score 2):

Even without quantum mechanics, the third law of thermodynamics only holds if there is a single lowest-energy state. For example, if there are two degenerate lowest-energy states, then the entropy is $k_B \log2$.